# What are the facilities for frames and templates in dreamweaver?

Tags: templates, dreamweaver, multimedia

What are the facilities for frames and templates in Adobe Dreamweaver?

Is it creating frames, creating nested frames and so on, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Frames:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7d48a.html

Templates:
Creating and managing templates:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7acda.html